# Brother DCP-195C Scanner not identified

Tags: 12.04, brother

I'm having trouble getting my Brother DCP-195C recognized as a scanner on Ubuntu 12.04. I've installed the drivers from Brother, but scanning programs, like `scangui` or `xsane` cannot see the device. I checked with `sane-find-scanner` and the scanner is listed:

```
found USB scanner (vendor=0x04f9 [Brother], product=0x0222 [DCP-195C]) at libusb:005:002
```

I added the udev rules as well to `/etc/udev/rules.d/60-libsane.rules`:

```
# Brother 
 ATTRS{idVendor}=="04f9", ENV{libsane_matched}="yes"
```

I've also tried linked the files from `/usr/lib64/` into `/usr/lib/`.

What else can I try?

Comment: Would you accept the answer that worked for you. I will be more easier to find it by others facing same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Try this solution, I find it on net

#### Printer

Download LPR driver and cupswrapper driver from [Brother Solution Center](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/BSC/public/eu/eu_ot/en/model_top/colormfc/dcp195c_all.html?reg=eu&c=eu_ot&lang=en&prod=dcp195c_all)

- Create directory /var/spool/lpd/dcp195c needed to install LPR driver
- Open a terminal as sudo and go to directory with drivers
- Install LPR driver

  ```
  dpkg -i --force-all dcp195clpr-1.1.2-1.i386.deb
  ```
- Install cupswrapper driver

  ```
  dpkg -i --force-all dcp195ccupswrapper-1.1.2-2.i386.deb
  ```
- Check LPR driver and cupswrapper driver are installed

  ```
  dpkg  -l  |  grep  Brother
  ```
- Check printer is on the cups web interface

#### Scanner

- Download the scanner driver (brscan3 for DCP-195C)
- Open the terminal, log in as sudo and go to directory with drivers
- Install the scanner driver

  ```
  dpkg  -i  --force-all  brscan3-0.2.11-2.amd64.deb
  ```
- Check the scanner driver is installed

  ```
  dpkg  -l  |  grep  Brother
  ```
- To enable scanner for a normal user, open for edit the following file

  ```
  nano /lib/udev/rules.d/40-libsane.rule
  ```
- Add the following lines to the end of the file and restart the system

  ```
  # Brother scanners
  ATTRS{idVendor}=="04f9", ENV{libsane_matched}="yes"
  ```

Comment: Your udev rules are wrong, the `Brother scanners` part should be a comment.

Comment: You are rigth. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

I think I downloaded the wrong versions of the drivers (an old search link perhaps). I went to Brother's site again and used their download search. I took the version listed [here](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public/eu/gb/en/dlf/download_index.html?reg=eu&c=gb&lang=en&prod=dcp195c_all&dlid=&flang=English&os=128&type2=-1) and installed (it is brscan3, not the brscan I had before). Once I did it appeared in my programs and works fine.